# Stack Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, stack

I have just finished a project for Post Fix Notation(RPN) using stack. I am not having much luck with some of the compiler errors so I come to you guys while I work on debugging on my side also.

This file given to us. We are suppose to derive a stack class from it.

```
#ifndef ABSTRACTSTACK_H
#define ABSTRACTSTACK_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

/* ---------------  Class 'Oops' ---------------
Class 
Thrown when an error is encountered.
Member 'm_msg' stores an error message.
*/
class Oops
{
    string m_errormsg;
    public:
    Oops(string msg) : m_errormsg(msg) {}
    const string& getMsg() const
    {
        return m_errormsg;
    }
};


/* ---------------  Abstract Class AbstractStack --------------- */
template < typename T >
class AbstractStack
{
public:

  // Purpose: Checks if a stack is empty
  // Returns: 'true' if the stack is empty
  //     'false' otherwise
  virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;


  // Purpose: looks at the top of the stack
  // Returns: a const reference to the element currently on top of the stack
  // Exception: if the stack is empty, THROW a 'Oops' object with an error message!!!
 virtual const T& top() const throw ( Oops ) = 0;

  // Purpose: push an element into the stack
  // Parameters: x is the value to push into the stack
  // Postconditions: x is now the element at the top of the stack,
  virtual void push(const T& x) = 0;

  // Purpose: pop the stack
  // Postconditions: the element formerly at the top of the stack has
  // been removed
  // Note: Poping an empty stack results in an empty stack.
  virtual void pop() = 0;


  // Purpose: clears the stack
  // Postconditions: the stack is now empty
  virtual void clear() = 0;

};

#endif
```

Here is my derived class and it's implementation.

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include "abstractstack.h"
using namespace std;



template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    T Data;
    Node<T>* next;
};


template<typename T> 
class Stack : public AbstactStack<T>
{
private:
Node<T>* Top;

public:

//Purpose: Destructor
//Postconditions: The stack is now empty
~Stack() {};

//Purpose: Default Constructor
//Postconditions: Top is initialized to 'NULL'
Stack(); Top(NULL){};

//Overloaded = Operator
//Postconditions: *this is now equal to rhs
const Stack<T>& operator = (const Stack<T>& rhs);


//Purpose: Check if a stack is empty
//Returns: 'true' if the stakc is empty, 'false' otherwise
bool isEmpty() const;

//Purpose: Looks at the top of the stack
//Returns: a const reference to the element currently on top of the stack
//Exception: if the stack is empty, THROW a 'Oops' object with an error message!!!"
const T& top() const throw(Oops);

    //Purpose: push an element into the stack
    //Parameters: x is the value to push into the stack
    //Postconditions: x is now the element at the top of the stack
    void push(const T& x);

     //Purpose: pop the stack
    //Postconditions: the element formerly at the top of the stack has been removed
   //Popping an empty stack results in an empty stack
   void pop();

    //Purpose: clears the stack
    //Postconditions: the stack is now empty
    void clear();

    //Reverses the stack
    //Postconditions: stack is now in reverse order
    void reverse();
};

#include "stack.hpp"
#endif
```

Implementation (.hpp)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



template<typename T>
const Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator = (const Stack<T>& rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
     {
        if (Top != NULL)
             clear();

        Node<T>* rhsPtr = rhs.Top;
        Node<T>* copyPtr = Top = new Node<T>;
        copyPtr->Data = rhsPtr->Data;
        while (rhsPtr->next != NULL)
        {
            rhsPtr = rhsPtr->next;
            copyPtr->next = new Node<T>;
            copyPtr = copyPtr->next;
            copyPtr->Data = rhsPtr->Data;
        }
        copyPtr->next = NULL;
    }
    return(*this)
}

template<typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const Stack<T>& rhs)
{
    Top = NULL;
    *this = rhs;
}

template<typename T>
bool Stack<T>::isEmpty()
{
    return(Top == NULL);
}

template<typename T>
const T& top() const throw(Oops)
{
    if (Top != NULL)
        return(Top->Data);
    else
        throw Oops(Stack is Empty!);

}

template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T& x)
{
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->Data = x;

    if (isEmpty())
   {
      Top = newNode;
      return;
    }

    newNode->next = Top;
    Top->next = newNode;

}

template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::pop()
{
    Node<T>* temp;
    if (Top != NULL)
    {
        temp = Top;
        Top = Top->next;
        delete temp;
    }
 }

template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::clear()
{
    Node<T>* temp;
    while (Top != NULL)
    {
        temp = Top;
        Top = Top->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::reverse()
{
    Node<T>* current;
    Node<T>* previous;
    Node<T>* next;

    previous = NULL;
    current = Top;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next = current->next;
        current->next = previous;
        previous = current;
        current = next;
    }

    Top = previous;
}
```

The compiler is unhappy with my Stack class. "stack.h:25:34: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
 class Stack : public AbstactStack

I've been told that I cannot inherit from Abstract because it is not a class but my professor tells me that it is fine and that I should add a forward declaration in my .cpp of Stack but I'm not sure how this goes. I know I am far from done but I would like to be able to solve at least this error so I can see if my program works correctly or not.

I posted my main program into Pastebin with its headers and implementation here in case it is needed. http://pastebin.com/1t2YGa2c

Comment: You just made a typo: `AbstactStack`.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me that the problem that you are having is just a typo in the following line :

```
class Stack : public AbstactStack<T>
```

Change `AbstactStack<T>` to `AbstractStack<T>` and this should work.

The error you are getting explains that the class name before the character `<` should be a template, but since you made a typo in the name of the class, it does not recognize.

Make sure you read and understand the error messages! They are often very helpful when solving problems like these.

Little side note : If you take a look at your error messages, you'll see the filename where the error is, followed by the line number and the column number (`stack.h:25:34`). Very useful information when debugging.

Comment: Wow! you reverse engineered the compiler error and the question!

Comment: @Arun Haha, error logs are there for a reason, so why not use them to our advantage? :)

Comment: Thanks guys. Spelling was the first thing that came to my mind but I guess I kept missing it.